# How can I predict a XAML Label's height on a Canvas

Tags: c#, xaml, canvas

I have an application where I need to dynamically build the content to a Canvas.  Everything works just fine, but I am a little unsure of how I can set the y coordinates for the labels in the safest way.  For example, I need to add three labels that are essentially lines of text.  In Java Swing or C# GDI I would just query the the font for the line height and add that value to the y coordinate of the drawText command.

This is my code.

```
double y = 0.0;
_line1.Content = "Line1";
_line1.SetValue(Canvas.TopProperty, y);
_line1.SetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty, 0.0);
CanvasChart.Children.Add(_line1);
double textHeight = _line1.Height;

y += textHeight;
_line2.Content = "Line2";
_line2.SetValue(Canvas.TopProperty, 0.0);
_line2.SetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty, y);
CanvasChart.Children.Add(_line2);
```

This does not work because _line1.Height does not seem to be set to anything useful at this point.  I suppose it has not rendered yet.  The above code is in the loaded event for the window.  ActualHeight does not help either.

Most code that I've seen seems to just set them to a hard coded value.  That I suppose looks right on the developer's display, and you just hope looks good at other resolutions/DPI.  In Swing and GDI I always had the best results finding out exactly how many pixels a string will be rendered at and using this to offset the next line.

Comment: It seems like you should be using a `StackPanel` or something similar. That way the controls will be positioned automatically. WPF is not designed to have controls laid out manually.

Comment: Normally I would use something like a StackPannel.  But in this case I am rendering a somewhat complex chart into a Canvas, and I simply need to know how big textual elements will be so that I can make sure not to overlap them (both with other text, and with lines).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must call the `Measure` method, specifying an infinite available size. This will update the `DesiredSize` of the control:

```
_line1.Measure(new Size(double.PositiveInfinity, double.PositiveInfinity));
double textHeight = _line1.DesiredSize.Height;
```

Another easy way to achieve the desired effect is to put the labels in a `StackPanel`.

Answer (score 1):

> In Swing and GDI I always had the best results finding out exactly how many pixels a string will be rendered at and using this to offset the next line.

This is possible in WPF as well.  The [`GlyphTypeface`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.glyphtypeface.aspx) class provides the `AdvanceWidths` and `AdvanceHeights` properties for each character in a typeface.  By using [`CharacterToGlyphMap`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.glyphtypeface.charactertoglyphmap.aspx), you can map a character to an index within the `AdvanceHeights`, and use that to determine the actual height of any character.

For a detailed example, see [GlyphRun and So Forth](http://smellegantcode.wordpress.com/2008/07/03/glyphrun-and-so-forth/).